# Why did Lester want to keep Ray Breslin in the Prison in movie "Escape Plan"?

Tags: plot-explanation, escape-plan

In the movie "[*Escape Plan*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1211956/)" why did Lester Clark pay/order Warden Hobbs to keep Ray in the prison?

What would he get out of that?

Answer (score 0):

This is explained at both IMDB and Wikipedia.

**He was offered a high-paying job running a similar prison.**

> Hobbs' illegal prison organization contacted Breslin & Clark so they could get infamous prison escaper out of the picture. They contacted Lester, and offered him a seven-figure salary with a job like Hobbs'
>
> <sup>[IMDB Synoposis](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1211956/synopsis?ref_=tt_stry_pl)</sup>
>
> Ross informs Breslin that they discovered Clark was offered a $5 million annual salary to become CEO of the security company, should Breslin's imprisonment prove that the ship is escape-proof.
>
> <sup>[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_Plan_(film))</sup>